# Higher derivatives of the log-partition function?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-information, partition-function

I need higher derivatives of the log-partition function $Z(z)=\log \sum_i \exp(z_i)$, has anyone derived the formula?

Looking at [concrete values](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/symmetric-softmax-decomposition.nb) of derivatives up to order 8, evaluated at $z=(1,1,1)$ makes me suspect there's a nice formula in terms of $p_i=\frac{\exp z_i}{Z}$

$$H_2=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{2}{9} & -\frac{1}{9} & -\frac{1}{9} \\
 -\frac{1}{9} & \frac{2}{9} & -\frac{1}{9} \\
 -\frac{1}{9} & -\frac{1}{9} & \frac{2}{9} \\
\end{array}
\right)=\text{diag}(p)-pp'
$$

$$H_3=\left[\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{2}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} \\
 -\frac{1}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} & \frac{2}{27} \\
 -\frac{1}{27} & \frac{2}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -\frac{1}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} & \frac{2}{27} \\
 -\frac{1}{27} & \frac{2}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} \\
 \frac{2}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -\frac{1}{27} & \frac{2}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} \\
 \frac{2}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} \\
 -\frac{1}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} & \frac{2}{27} \\
\end{array}\right)
\right]$$

Answer (score 0):

The higher order derivatives of the free energy gives you the central moments of the energy (which in your case is the discrete random variable $z$ with distribution $p$).

For instance, the first derivative yeilds the mean energy, the second derivative yields the variance, and the $k$'th derivative yields the $k$'th central moment.

You can refer to the following Wikipedia page about cumulants:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant